# Threads slow down main loop

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

I'm currently on phone and can't get the full code. It' based on pygame.
But its something like this:

```
def func():
    #Bunch of for loops that needs 0.2 secs
#Main loop
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    thr=Thread(target=func) 
    thr. start() 
    #Here it draws frames(it should be 60 per second, but because of threads, it's only 5)
```

These threads reduce frame rate.(They lag the main loop)
I know that the clock.tick(60) isn't problem here. Should I create thread for this while loop?

Comment: In Python, the global interpreter lock (GIL) means that only one thread can "use" the Python interpreter at a time, so it can cause slow down when you have multiple threads. Adding another thread might just reduce the frame-rate further though your mileage might vary.

Comment: @Matt Clarke And what can I do to have 2 loops(or more) running at the same time without slowing down?

Comment: I don't know anything about pygame, so it might be that there is something built in to help. Otherwise, the usual option in Python is to use multi-processing instead of threading, but that might not work for your needs. Can I ask what you do in func(), is it something that needs to be done on every frame?

Comment: @Matt Clarke Yes, There is a AI that needs to calculate where to move. If I do it in any other way(like execution every 1 second) it doesnt work properly).

Comment: From the code above it seems you create a new thread every time you go around the main loop - this is likely to introduce a significant delay as creating a thread takes time. Perhaps it is possible to create the thread once outside and instead send messages to it when you need it to process? Without more context this is only a guess, but it may provide some speed up.

Comment: Threads are more efficient when downloading data. You could try `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you spawning threads like no tomorrow in the `while True` loop?

I don't think there exists one case where this could be beneficial to your program.

I would strongly advise to manage carefully the number of your threads in your program and joining them if they are not `daemon`.